# Shortcut for google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I need to create a shortcut for google spreadsheet on MAC OS,

Is there any way to create a shortcut for the particular google spreadsheet on Desktop, So that I can click on it and it will directly open to the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

Since every Google Spreadsheet document has its own unique URL it is no different than any other webpage. So, if you want to have a shortcut on Desktop (Mac OS):

1. Open that Google Spreadsheet in your preferred browser
2. Drag an icon that appear on the left of an URL address to your Desktop. If you don't see your Desktop, just press F11 while dragging

I attached an image what icon I mean (Safari as an example browser).

[image: Safari url icon]

Answer (score -1):

This is possible.

- Copy the url from the browser.
- Go to your desktop.
- Rightclick on a blank place.
- Choose New > Shortcut.
- Paste the url in the first screen.
- Give the shortcut your desired name.
- Double click the shortcut and your standard browser should open the url (which is the spreadsheet).

Comment: Sorry I forget to Mention, I need this for Mac OS

Comment: Okay, don't have an Mac. Can't help you with that.

Comment: Roodey Thanks anyways :)